# A polynomial in 3 (commuting) variables which only gives 2 distinct polynomials (including itself) on permuting variables

Tags: group-theory, polynomials, permutations, group-actions

[This is a question from Oxford.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLlUp.jpg) I am stuck at last part. It says that every divisor of n! occurs when n=3 so that includes 2 but i cant find a polynomial in 3  (commuting) variables which only gives 2 distinct polynomials (including itself) on permuting variables

Comment: Hard to help here without actually revealing a solution. Think like this: $x_1-x_2$ would change sign when acted on by the permutation $(1 2)$ - but it is also not invariant to the cycles such as $(1 2 3)$. However, can you use it as a building block of something that will change sign on swap of any three variables?

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thanks!  I got it. It must be $(x_{1}-x_{2})(x_{2}-x_{3})(x_{2}-x_{3})$.  I did consider just $x_{1}-x_{2}$ but didn't think of it as a building block